# Can I run Mac OS X as a Hyper-V Virtual Machine?

Tags: macos, virtualization, windows-server-2008, hyper-v

I would like to know if it is possible, (not from a legality standpoint, but from a technical standpoint), to run Mac OS X on a Hyper-V VM. This would make testing so much easier as I would not have to go dig up and old Mac or find someone and borrow their laptop.

Comment: you can definitely run it on a VMWare vm running VMWare Player

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. Hyper-V is very specific about supported OS's and the generic drivers are very Microsoft specific.

Comment: Don't want you to think I went over your head on this one. I was unaware that you had closed a previous version of this as a dupe until I saw it on the related list. I went ahead and deleted the older one.

Comment: @The TXI - No hard feelings at all. I abide by the older mods and have been on a bit of a closing spree.

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to BinaryMisfit's answer, **apparently it is possible**, although not supported by either Apple or Microsoft.

In the past, I've heard that people have found it easier to run Mac OS X using VMware Workstation, or possibly VirtualBox (with a bit more work), and Hyper-V used less for this, but I'm told it's possible.

I will quote the steps as mentioned in [this Github thread](https://github.com/acidanthera/bugtracker/issues/2179), which refers to using [MacHyperVSupport](https://github.com/acidanthera/MacHyperVSupport) as published on Github:

> It is pretty simple to use MacHyperVSupport.kext under Hyper-V.
>
> ###### Prerequisites: Prepare the EFI folder and config.plist.
>
> - You can start from https://github.com/acidanthera/OpenCorePkg/blob/master/Docs/Sample.plist as
>   the base of your config.plist.
> - Apply all necessary changes documented in https://github.com/acidanthera/MacHyperVSupport/blob/master/README.md.
>   You don't need to apply all the changes unless you want to run a very
>   old version of macOS.
> - Add all the essential kexts including MacHyperVSupport.kext
>
> ###### Create the boot VHDX
>
> - You can create a small 1GB VHDX, initialize as GUID partition table (GPT), and format as FAT32
> - Place your EFI folder under the root. You should have directories EFI\Boot and EFI\OC. Technically you need to use EFI system partition,
>   but Hyper-V recognizes regular FAT32 partition.
>
> ###### Prepare installer or recovery VHDX. (Only need to pick one)
>
> - You can follow the doc https://github.com/acidanthera/MacHyperVSupport/blob/master/README.md about
>   create and use the installer. This may need another Mac to do.
> - You can also create a recovery VHDX. https://dortania.github.io/OpenCore-Install-Guide/installer-guide/winblows-install.html is
>   your best friend to guide you, and replace the USB with the recovery
>   VHDX you created.
>
> ###### Install macOS
>
> - Create a Generation 2 VM
> - Disable Secure Boot on the VM
> - Attach the boot VHDX, installer/recovery VHDX created above
> - Create an empty VHDX for the final macOS installation
> - Boot the VM and select Recovery or Installer
> - Follow the screen to install the operating system
>
> You should have macOS running under Hyper-V now. Hope this helps.
>
> Many thanks to the acidanthera team for making this happen.

[This thread on InsanelyMac.com](https://www.insanelymac.com/forum/topic/323303-macos-on-hyper-v/) also offers some additional tips.

Answer (score -1):

If you have access to it, VMware Fusion can run macOS. Virtualbox and VMWare player can as well, but it's unclear whether it's legal.

Comment: “… but it's unclear whether it's legal.” It is very clear that if you own a Mac you a virtualize macOS. If you just have some copy of macOS you got somewhere, then guess what? Illegal.