# Win2k8R2 + Hyper-V + MacPro = Virtualized OSX Allowed?

Tags: macos, virtualization, hyper-v

I have an older (2007 or 2008 I think) Mac Pro. Its a Dual Dual Xeon 2.6 with 12GB RAM. I installed Windows 2008 R2 Server on it with HyperV. Apple have something in their license that specifies OSX Server can be Virtualized if its running on Apple Hardware. And I think I read somewhere, but cant seem to find the link, that OSX Client (Lion) should allow the same... So, my questions are as follows:

- Can I run OSX server or client on a HyperV machine, as long as the underlying hardware is Apple?
- If so, how do I install OSX Server/Client on HyperV? I know Microsoft probably don't support it, but given i can install Ubuntu, which is not supported, and FreeBSD, which in theory is similar to OSX, it should work, right?

I have seen install tutorials for VMWare and Virtual Box, but not HyperV... Am I missing something?

Comment: You may virtualize OS X server and OS X Lion, so legally, that's fine I suppose. But possible? Regarding Hyper-V, [I don't think so](http://superuser.com/questions/25893/can-i-run-mac-os-x-as-a-hyper-v-virtual-machine) -- but the question is a bit older.

Comment: The HyperV support may have changed since that last question.... 2k8R2 has been released, and even though Microsoft dont support more operating systems (still some distros of Linux and Windows) FreeBSD will work, as will many others.... The Syntetic drivers (i think thats what there called... the ones in the HyperV components) will mainly only work with Windows, and there are some in the Linux Kernel, but in theory if FreeBSD works, so should OSX... in theory... Will see if i can maybe walk though the VMWare tutorials and see if they work...