# Why won't Mac OS run on Hyper-V

Tags: macos, hyper-v

I have been trying to run Mac OS on Hyper-V, but it won't work. Any suggestions? I have tried, but it just makes a long error.

Comment: [related](https://superuser.com/q/25893/172747)